# Basic English to Pig Latin translation in python

Tags: python

I want to make a Pig Latin translator.

`translate_sentence(" No shirts, no shoes, no service")` should produce this:

```
Onay irtsshay, onay oesshay, onay ervicesay
```

Here is my code:

```
sentence = sentence.split()
for item in range(len(sentence)):
    if sentence[item][0] in "aeiou":
        sentence[item] += 'yay'
    else:
        sentence[item]=sentence[item][1:]+sentence[item][0]
        sentence[item]+='ay'
sentence = ' '.join(sentence)

print(sentence)
```

Comment: Please read [ask] and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: I would second @kaya3 's assertion that you should review [ask].  As of the revision I'm looking at right now, the post lacks a clear question statement-- you state your requirements and show your code-- did you have a question or issue?

Comment: @tony we don't do homework on SO.

Answer (score 0):

Cool challenge, here is my solution:

```
sentence = "hello my name is Ari"

# split words into a list
tokens = sentence.split(" ")

# Iterate over the list of words
for word in tokens:

    # Store the words position in the list for later
    word_index = tokens.index(word)

    # If the first character is a vowel, we'll do this
    if word[0].lower() in ('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'):
        tokens[word_index] = word + "yay"

    # If it's not we're going to do this...
    else:
        tokens[word_index] = word[1:] + word[0] + "ay"

print(" ".join(tokens))
```

Output:

```
ellohay ymay amenay isyay Ariyay
```

Comment: Couldn't you just use `enumerate()` to get the `word_index`?

Comment: You could, there's 1000 ways to skin a cat, so the saying goes.

Comment: yes, but every time fetching the index using `index()` sounds a lot of work. : )

Comment: We're not going for optimization here, it's just a simple english to piglatin script. When I start translating full sized books I'll consider your suggestion :)

Comment: But your solution has same logic as OP's attempt and it will produce wrong output for words like `this`. Your solution will generate `histay` but it should be `isthay`

Comment: is this python 3? or the latest python code?